# Error when refreshing software cache

Tags: update-manager

I have changed few settings on Software & Updates and it wanted to reload something but I got this error message saying "pk-client-error-quark: could not do untrusted question as no klass support". What does that mean and how can fix it?

Ubuntu version 20.04.2 LTS.